# Logstash not able to read simple file

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

I am learning logstash and simply I am trying to read a file and try to put output in file. Log file format is

```
LogName      : System
LogName      : System
```

Here is the conf file -

```
input{
file {
    path => "<mypath>\wineventlog.txt"
    type => 'eventlog'
}
}
filter{
    if "eventlog" in [type] {
        grok {
            match => { 'message' => 'LogName\W+(?<LogName>[A-Za-z]{0,})'
                     }
            }
     }  
}
output{

  file{
        path => "<mypath>\output.txt"
  }

}
```

but when I run output file has

```
{"path":"<mypath>\\wineventlog.txt","@timestamp":"2017-04-11T16:17:40.732Z","@version":"1","host":"INFARSZB11617","message":"\u0000L\u0000o\u0000g\u0000N\u0000a\u0000m\u0000e\u0000 \u0000 \u0000 \u0000 \u0000 \u0000 \u0000:\u0000 \u0000S\u0000y\u0000s\u0000t\u0000e\u0000m\u0000\r\u0000","type":"eventlog","tags":["_grokparsefailure"]}
{"path":"<mypath>\\wineventlog.txt","@timestamp":"2017-04-11T16:17:40.748Z","@version":"1","host":"INFARSZB11617","message":"\u0000\r\u0000","type":"eventlog","tags":["_grokparsefailure"]}
```

Please guide me what to do here. FYI, I tried to remove filter in conf file, then I don't get any output files.

Thanks
Debashree

Comment: Just to add with above.. I am running this in Windows 10

Comment: I am able to close this issue but making sure the input log is in ASCII

Comment: Why aren't you using GREEDYDATA or DATA in GROK? It will be easier and faster.